# Notify a public group on Escalation

Tags: case, escalation

I want to notify a public group on Escalation of case. I have created a Escalation process on case. And now I want to send a notification email to a public group. But I am only able to find a notify notify this user option on Escalation action. Is their any way to notify a public group when case Escalation occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You can, however, create a group email on your company's mail server and have Salesforce notify that address.

Comment: That is, create a User `case-escalation@mycompany.com` - use that user in the Notify user section of the Escalation Rules, and have the mail server distribute this to its members